# How would I go about modifying this JS to allow for multiple modals?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, I should have been more clear. I don't want to show 2 modals at the same time. I have 2 buttons, each opening a different modal.

I'm using some JS I found at Codepen for a modal dialog. Everything works like a charm as long as I use 1 modal. However, I'm wanting to use 2 different modals on the same page. How would I go about modifying the code to allow for multiple modals? I've tried everything from modifying the code to copying everything and pasting/renaming it. Everything I do seems to break the modal. Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
<div class="modal-overlay1">
  <div class="modal-window1">
    <h1>Welcome to the modal window!</h1>
    <p>This is a pop up that may contain a form or other info</p>
    <button class="close-button">Close popup</button>
</div>

  <div class="modal-overlay2">
  <div class="modal-window2">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>test</p>
    <button class="close-button">Close popup</button>
</div>
```

Codepen link:
http://codepen.io/brouxhaha/pen/veADg

Comment: Are you trying to display multiple modals at the same time? If so, you might misunderstand what `modal` means.

Comment: You only need one modal. Change the content of the modal depending on what you want to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nDCey

js:

```
function Modal(modalEl, overlayEl, handler) {
  this.modal = $(modalEl);
  this.overlay = $(overlayEl);
  this.handler = $(handler);
  this.wWidth = $(window).width();
  this.wHeight = $(window).height();
  this.dHeight = $(document).height();
}
...
$(function(){
  new Modal('#mw1', '#m1', '#ml1').init();
  new Modal('#mw2', '#m2', '#ml2').init();        
});
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <p id="ml1" class="modal-link">Click to open modal1</p>
  <p id="ml2" class="modal-link">Click to open modal2</p>
</div>

<div id="m1" class="modal-overlay">
  <div id="mw1" class="modal-window">
    <h1>Welcome to the modal window!</h1>
    <p>This is a pop up that may contain a form or other info</p>
    <button class="close-button">Close popup</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="m2" class="modal-overlay">
  <div id="mw2" class="modal-window">
    <h1>Welcome to the modal window 2!</h1>
    <p>Modal number two</p>
    <button class="close-button">Close popup</button>
  </div>
</div>
```